# mysql delete with select multi conditions

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to delete this specific column?
This is not working. 
Although, SELECT works fine in mysql, it's tested.

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE table2.ID IN (SELECT * FROM table2, table1
WHERE table2.tableID = 2 and table1.level = 1 and table1.ID = 1)
```

To add, table1 and table2 have columns:

```
table1(table1.id, table1.name, table1.level) 

table2(table2.id, table1.id)
```

I have two tables:

**users**

```
userid username userleve
1       dani     1
2       mark     2
```

**games**

```
 gameid   userid  cluba        clubb     resa   resb
  1        1      liverpool    chealsea    1     1
  2        2      Aston Villa  Watford     0     0
  3        1      Sunderland   Swansea City 2     1
```

> There is no FK between tables and i need to delete 1 row entered by
>   specific user with specific level.

Comment: You need to `SELECT ID`, and it wouldn't delete the column, it would delete the rows whose ID is in the results of the select....and your SELECT doesn't give the impression of this making any sort of sense. Why involve table1 at all when there is no join condition?

Comment: @Dani do you mean you want to delete a specific `row` instead?

Comment: @DrewPierce I agree, it appears there is no relation between the two tables if the `ID'`s are different.

Comment: yes,row. not colomn.

Comment: i have table1.userID in table2, but its not FK

Comment: simplfy, i have table users(userid, username, userlevel) and table games(gamesid, userid)

Comment: there is no FK between tables and i need to delete 1 row entered by specific user with specific level.

Comment: @Dani Based on your sample data above, nobody will be deleted because it does not match your where clause criteria of  `userID = 2 and userlevel = 1`. Check it out here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/140cdc/1/0

Comment: it works man!!!! thanx! where can i say that it is answered?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM games
USING games
JOIN users ON games.userid = users.userid  
WHERE games.userID = 2
and users.userlevel = 1;

select * from users;

select * from games;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/987f2b/1/0)

Comment: this needs some work i believe, i am often wrong :)  a Fiddle?

Comment: @DrewPierce I think you are absolutely right. :) I am going to delete this because it is not clear what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I just realized he is asking to delete a 'column'? I am confused now. :)

Comment: s.o. is confusing. i don't think he is trying to alter table and drop  a column

Comment: if i try the whole code, it does only 'select', if i try without last to lines, it deletes nothing.

Comment: @Dani Check out my SQLFiddle example, it should work for you if you are just trying to delete a single row from the games table.

Comment: @Dani Did that work for you? If so, please feel free to mark it as accepted answer so others will know this question has been answered.

Comment: sorry, didn't see it well....query executes, but 0 rows deleted...everything is still there.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data from both your `users` and `games` tables?

Comment: I would add that to your question along with some other sample data for games tables.

Comment: this is confusing and for me , now :D